# Connecting a manually created Gnosis Safe to the Safe UI

Tags: gnosis-safe, proxy-contracts, safe-core-sdk, create2, safe-core

I have a Safe at https://etherscan.io/address/0x000000000034065b3a94c2118cfe5b4c0067b615#readProxyContract, and I was having trouble connecting it to both the Safe Web and Safe Mobile apps. When entering the address, I see this error: `Address given is not a valid Safe address`:
[image: Address given is not a valid Safe address]

I didn't use the Safe UI to deploy, but it is still deployed from the canonical v1.4.1 factory on mainnet https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets/v1.4.1, which uses these addresses:

- factory:   0x4e1DCf7AD4e460CfD30791CCC4F9c8a4f820ec67
- singleton: 0x41675C099F32341bf84BFc5382aF534df5C7461a
- fallback:  0xfd0732Dc9E303f09fCEf3a7388Ad10A83459Ec99

It seems the transaction did not have a "proxy" field set though, [my transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdac58edb65c2af3f86f03586eeec7caa7ee245d6d06679a913e5dda16617658e#eventlog) has this:
[image: manual]

while a typical UI created safe has this:
[image: ui]
This might be specific to v1.4.1, as [other createProxyWithNonce() transactions](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07a41308b4b7b44084feecd6ce6f424b0b56f4edea1265eb86dde87610819de0#eventlog) don't have this `proxy` field.

Questions:

- Do I need to verify this contract, and if so how should I do this?
- If the above isn't the issue, what do I need to do to be able to connect this to Safe UI/Web/Mobile apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since the proxy address is indexed, it's now pushed to topics. If you look closely, the address is there in the topics.
2. 1.4.1 is not supported on the UI/infra level yet; it will be supported in the UI once the support is implemented.

Comment: Thanks @mikheevm, is there any rough ETA on when we should expect UI/infra support?

Comment: Or are there details on what exactly needs to be updated on the UI/infra layer? Open to helping with the change myself if it's open source.

Comment: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-transaction-service/issues/1433

Comment: This is better asked in the web team discord or repos since it's out of the scope of the dev support.

Comment: Great, thank you!